# HashMap iterator ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, websocket, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I'm getting `ConcurrentModificationException` and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm having an Android multithread application (communicating with sockets) and I'm storing callbacks (interface) into a hashmap.

```
public class ApiManager {

   private static ApiManager instance;

   public synchronized ApiManager getInstance() {
      if (instance == null)
         instance = new ApiManager();

      return instance;  
   }

   private final HashMap<String, Callback> callbacks = new HashMap<>;

   // Setters and getters for storing callbacks

   private @Nullable Callback getCallback(@NoNull String key) {
      synchronized (callbacks) {
         return callbacks.get(key);
      }
   }

   private void addCallback(@NonNull String key, @NonNull Callback callback) {
      synchronized (callbacks) {
         callbacks.put(key, callback); 
      }
   }

   private void removeCallback(@NonNull String key) {
       synchronized (callbacks) {
          callbacks.remove(key);
       }
   }

   // Request to retrieve the user's profile from server
   public synchronized void getProfile(String key, Callback callback) {
      // Save the callback
      addCallback(key, callback);

      // Do the asynchronous request
      getSocket().emit("getProfile", new Ack() {
         @Override
         public void call(Object... args) {
            // Deliver the response
            Callback callback = getCallback(key);
            if (callback != null)
               callback.onResponse(args);  

            // Remove the callback
            removeCallback(key);                
         }
      });
   }

   // Called when the socket disconnects
   // ----> This is the method where I get the exception !
   private void onSocketDisconnect() {

      /*
       * Notify stored callbacks that the socket has disconnected
       */ 

      synchronized (callbacks) {
         Set<Map.Entry<String, Callback>> set = callbacks.entrySet();
         if (set.size() > 0) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Callback>> iterator = set.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               // This is the line where the exception occurres
               Map.Entry<String, Callback> entry = iterator.next();

               String key = entry.getKey();
               Callback callback = entry.getValue();

               if (callback != null) {
                  // Notify callback that there was a socket disconnect exception
                 callback.onResponse(Factory.buildResponseFailure(SOCKET_DISC));

                  it.remove();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And sometimes an exception occurres:

```
Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:851)
       at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:891)
       at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:890)
```

This is how I retrieve the user's profile:

```
ApiManager.getInstance().getProfile(KEY_PROFILE_REQ, new Callback() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Object... args) {
      // Parsing the data 
   }
});
```

As you can see I'm accessing the hashmap in a `synchronized` block. The `ApiManager` class is a singleton. Why am I getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` if I lock the object while iterating it? How does other threads obtains the lock? Am I missing something?

Note: In this example are 3 threads. UI thread (where I call the `getProfile()` method), the 2nd thread is the socket's inner thread (delivery response) and another thread which calls the `onSocketDisconnected()` method.

Comment: In your while (iterator.hasNext()) block call iterator.remove after accessing data.

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-how-to-handle-concurrent-modification-exception/

Answer (score 0):

Removing an item from a collection while iterating over the same could cause this. Have you tried storing the items to be removed somewhere and then, after you have processed the final element, set.removeAll(somewhere)?